# SQL Server Replace Command with WIldcard

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am in need of some help. Thanks to fellow user davids, I was able to get certain things working within SQL Server and am in need of some more help. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET keyfield=(REPLACE(REPLACE(Column1,'http://*/folder/',''),'.avi',''))
UPDATE Table2 SET keyfield=(REPLACE(REPLACE(Column2,'http://server2/folder/',''),'.mpg',''))
```

Can anyone help me out or point me in the right direction to get the wildcard to work? This particular column, the * is an IP Address and it will change all the time. Granted I will know the IP's ahead of time and can probably do it one by one, but I would prefer to have it automatically replace. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add a before and after for the keyfield?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into regular expressions.

My google karma found [this article in MSDN Magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx#S2).

**Edit:**

See also:
[Perform regex (replace) in an SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150977/perform-regex-replace-in-an-sql-query)

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. After looking at everything I had to revamp what I was doing. In the process I also figured out an easier way for me to do the replace in the process. Figured out my issue and learned something new, thank you for the help!

Comment: your google karma has expired: that link doesn't work any more.

Comment: @Brad The woe of link-only answers. Not sure what to do. The question has a great subject line (but is otherwise not great). The accepted answer of the question I link to in the Edit does a great job of answering this question. My answer doesn't provide any additional value. I propose that we try to close this question as a dupe so that people who find it get directed to a proper answer.