# How can I do SQL Server RegEx replace similar to JavaScript RegEx replace

Tags: sql-server, regex, string, replace

How can perform below shown JavaScript RegEx replace in SQL Server?

```
var str = "$5,000";
console.log(str.replace(/[$,]/g, ""));
```

Output:

```
5000
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13253259/sql-server-replace-command-with-wildcard and maybe http://stackoverflow.com/a/31693412/3832970.

Comment: No regex needed in this case. SQL server has the money type, and you can cast that to an int or a bigint for large numbers. `cast(cast('$5,000' as money) as int)`

Comment: @lukstorms thanks for a cleaner solution

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
declare @str money
set @str= cast(cast('$5,000' as money) as int)
```

Or else if you especially want to use regular expression, you can try the below,

```
DECLARE @Str varchar(100)
SET @Str = '$5,000' 
set @Str = STUFF(@Str, PATINDEX('%[$,]%', @Str),1, '')
select @str
```

Comment: the result is '5,000' and I want the result as '5000'

Comment: Just do a double replace `replace(replace(@Str,'$',''),',','')` then.  PATINDEX only gives the first occurrence of a match.