# I want to remove part of string from a string

Tags: sql, t-sql

Thank you in advance.

I want to remove string after *.* including *.*, but length is variable and string can be of any length.

1)Example:
 Input:- `SCC0204.X  and FRK0005.X  and RF0023.X and ADF1010.A and HGT9010.V`

Output:  `SCC0204 and FRK0005 and RF0023 and ADF1010.A and HGT9010.V`

I tried using the charindex but as the length keeps on changing i wasn't able to do it. I want to trim the values with ending with only X

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there always exactly one dot?

Comment: are you using oracle?

Comment: yes i have only one dot. and i want to trim the values with only `.X` and i am using mssql 2010

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming there is only one dot

```
UPDATE TABLE 
SET column_name = left(column_name, charindex('.', column_name) - 1)
```

For SELECT

```
select left(column_name, charindex('.', column_name) - 1) AS col
from your_table
```

Answer (score 3):

Hope this helps. The code only trims the string when the value has a decimal "." in it and if that value is equal to `.X`

```
;WITH cte_TestData(Code) AS
(
SELECT 'SCC0204.X' UNION ALL
SELECT 'FRK0005.X' UNION ALL
SELECT 'RF0023.X' UNION ALL
SELECT 'ADF1010.A' UNION ALL
SELECT 'HGT9010.V' UNION ALL
SELECT 'SCC0204' UNION ALL
SELECT 'FRK0005'
)
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN CHARINDEX('.', Code) > 0 AND RIGHT(Code,2) = '.X'
            THEN SUBSTRING(Code, 1, CHARINDEX('.', Code) - 1)
        ELSE Code
        END
FROM cte_TestData
```

If the criteria is only to replace remove `.X` then probably this should also work

```
;WITH cte_TestData(Code) AS
(
SELECT 'SCC0204.X' UNION ALL
SELECT 'FRK0005.X' UNION ALL
SELECT 'RF0023.X' UNION ALL
SELECT 'ADF1010.A' UNION ALL
SELECT 'HGT9010.V' UNION ALL
SELECT 'SCC0204' UNION ALL
SELECT 'FRK0005'
)
SELECT REPLACE (Code,'.X','')
FROM cte_TestData
```

Answer (score 1):

Use LEFT String function :

```
 DECLARE @String VARCHAR(100) = 'SCC0204.XXXXX'
 SELECT LEFT(@String,CHARINDEX('.', @String) - 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet here is to create a function that parses the string and uses regex. I hope this old post helps:

[Perform regex (replace) in an SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150977/perform-regex-replace-in-an-sql-query)

However, if the value you need to trim is constantly ".X", then you should use
    **select replace(string, '.x', '')**

Comment: Add required code from link you given as if code inside link will get changed it may not be useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the below code. I think this will help you.

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(100) = 'SCC0204.X'
IF (SELECT RIGHT(@String,2)) ='.X'
   SELECT LEFT(@String,CHARINDEX('.', @String) - 1)
ELSE 
  SELECT @String
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** I just missed one of the comments where the OP clarifies the requirement. What I put together below is how you would deal with a requirement to remove everything after the first dot on strings ending with X. I leave this here for reference.

```
;WITH cte_TestData(Code) AS
(
  SELECT 'SCC0204.X'  UNION ALL -- ends with '.X'
  SELECT 'FRK.000.X'  UNION ALL -- ends with '.X', contains multiple dots
  SELECT 'RF0023.AX'  UNION ALL -- ends with '.AX'
  SELECT 'ADF1010.A'  UNION ALL -- ends with '.A'
  SELECT 'HGT9010.V'  UNION ALL -- ends with '.V'
  SELECT 'SCC0204.XF' UNION ALL -- ends with '.XF'
  SELECT 'FRK0005'    UNION ALL -- totally clean
  SELECT 'ABCX'                 -- ends with 'X', not dots
)
SELECT 
  orig_string = code,
  newstring   = 
  SUBSTRING
  (
    code, 1,
    CASE 
      WHEN code LIKE '%X'
      THEN ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('.',code)-1, -1), LEN(code))
      ELSE LEN(code)
    END
  )
FROM cte_TestData;
```

FYI - SQL Server 2012+ you could simplify this code like this:

```
SELECT 
  orig_string = code,
  newstring   = 
  SUBSTRING(code, 1,IIF(code LIKE '%X', ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('.',code)-1, -1), LEN(code)), LEN(code)))
FROM cte_TestData;
```

Answer (score 0):

With SUBSTRING you can achieve your requirements by below code.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(column_name, 0, CHARINDEX('.', column_name)) AS col
FROM your_table
```

If you want to remove fixed **.X** from string you can also use REPLACE function.

```
SELECT REPLACE(column_name, '.X', '') AS col
```